# Are questions asked in conlangs accepted on this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We anticipate conlang specialists on this site, and, most naturally, some of them are familiar with popular conlangs to an extent that they can express fluently and discuss various matters using that languages.

Also, several constructed languages are even more suited for logic and the accurate delivery of the meaning due to their syntactic unambiguity (like Lojban).

Considering the above, **do we accept questions asked in (popular) conlangs?**

Comment: With a few exceptions (mostly about Esperanto, I fear), those questions would attract no answers and no comments. So, what would be the point?

Comment: I agree with the "no" answers. However, I think *chatrooms* for conversation in conlangs would be fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**I don't think this is a good idea to allow on-site.**

Stack Exchange is a resource for future visitors as much as it is a site we participate on now. English is the official language of Stack Exchange, except where sites are dedicated to other languages. That's the case because we want all people to be able to read all questions. For the same reasons Stack Overflow doesn't allow non-English questions, I don't think allowing questions in conlangs is practical here.

On top of that, most people don't have the fluency in conlangs as natural languages. Questions asked in conlangs are extremely liable to be misinterpreted. I speak from experience trying to participate on conlang-only forums - this isn't wild speculation. It really is difficult to impossible to do well. That's part of the fun, mind, but SE a forum is not.

Comment: "*English is the official language of Stack Exchange, **except where sites are dedicated to other languages***" - which this site is?

Comment: @Rand No, not the same - Stack Overflow Portugese, for example, is what I mean. Sites dedicated to other languages means sites whose _primary language_ is another language.

Comment: @Zyerah But sites like [french.se] and [german.se], for example, accept questions and answers written entirely in French/German, *as well as* those written in English. I think that's a better analogy here than e.g. Portuguese SO. (But you make a good point that fluency in conlangs is far rarer.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor French & German language SE's (as well as Japanese and all the others) are restricted to only 1 non-english language though. On here this would not be the case. So it's kind of a non-argument :/

Comment: @Rand Those language sites have a critical mass of speakers with sufficient fluency to correctly and regularly understand what's being said.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Saying "they're restricted to 1 non-english language" doesn't change it. What about it being only one language matters more than having a handful?

Comment: @corsiKa what Zyerah said just above your comment

Answer (score 10):

**No**

Stacks are meant as a Q&A resource for people all over the world. Aside from a [few exceptions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), all stacks are enforcing use of the English language. As English is one of the worlds more important languages and on most school curriculums nowadays, this allows people from everywhere to chip in and excludes almost nobody.

Questions and answers that are composed in a con-language would exclude, I daresay, most users of the stack from reading/understanding them. It would also make it very hard for community moderation to work as most people handling flags, etc. would likely not be fluent in the respective language.

The language learning stacks seem an exception to the above by mostly allowing questions to be posed either in English or the respective language they are dedicated to, but as this is meant as a general conlang stack I do not see that working either.

Answer (score -5):

**Yes, this should be allowed**

Languages are intended to be answered by experts, and to solve expert problems. If someone is unable to read a post in a language, they really have no business even attempting to answer the question.

When I ask a question on Stack Overflow about a particular framework, I expect only people with expert knowledge in that framework to even read, let alone answer, the question. I don't attempt to say "If I were doing this in regular Java I'd do _____" just so more people can attempt to understand the question.

Such an exercise may help me solve the problem myself, but so would a myriad of other techniques, none of which are required. So yes, if someone wants to ask a question in a particular language, they should feel free to do so. Sites dedicated to specific languages allow this, I see no reason why the same logic shouldn't apply to this site.

Comment: It's entirely possible to be knowledgeable in the grammar and mechanics of a language (especially a constructed language) without fluency. Perhaps Ithkuil is an extreme case, but I can say for sure that plenty of experienced Ithkuilists are not able to construct or interpret sentences at any reasonable rate. Even after having several-sentence discussions in Ithkuil, the participants will usually confirm in English that their messages were conveyed accurately.

Comment: I don't know of any SE site where posting a program in some specific programming language, with no further explanation in natural language, is considered okay.

Comment: @Pseudonym in theory there's the Codereview stack where this seems mostly ok

Comment: Another issue with this is the moderation of such posts. If people are unable to read a post in a conlang they're not familiar with, they'll have a hard time determining if it's an answer or not. Additionally, diamond moderators (further down the line), like any other users, won't know the majority of the conlangs used on the site.

Comment: @HDE226868 Somehow I anticipate the number of spam messages in Klingon to be quite low. But on SO if someone posts in a programming language with which I'm not familiar, I also often won't be able to tell if it's a reasonable answer or not I don't see a difference here.