# Chatting in conlangs

Tags: discussion, chat

Related: [Are questions asked in conlangs accepted on this site?](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/8)

I thought, as this is a site about languages, it wouldn't be a bad idea to have a separate chatroom for talking ***in*** conlangs. Well, I didn't create one yet. I thought that I should first ask here.

- Is it ok to talk in conlangs in the main chatroom? Is there even a need for the separate room?
- Should there be a single chatroom for this or rather one room per language?
- Does it make sense to create such room?

Comment: <<qatlhbe'?>>  ;-) (Joke in Klingon: it asks "Why not?")

Answer (score 11):

Few people are very proficient in many conlangs, especially if you exclude Esperanto which I assume already has chat rooms. Anyone can make chat rooms if they want, so go ahead, but I wouldn't expect it to be all that well populated considering the size of the site.

As for the main chat room, I'd say no, keep that to English.

Answer (score 2):

I think chat in an invented language ought to be encouraged; but as curiousdannii says, keep the main chatroom in English.

**Caveat:**

It is also common courtesy to provide, at the least, a translation of what's being said for the benefit of everyone else who doesn't know the language being used.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I don't think that's a good idea except for perhaps a few languages with a large user base. Moderators need to be able to read chat messages.